# Error shows when trying to apply a shader from Renderman 21 materials library to a model!

Tags: error, renderman-render-engine

I've installed Rendeman21 to Blender today and I found out that this render engine has its own library of materials, but when I try to add a material to one of my models, this pops up!

[image]

Comment: What material are you trying to apply? Please be a little more specific.

Comment: The same error shows up for all the materials I'm trying to apply (from the library)

Comment: Looks like a bug in the script and should be reported to the script author. Not much we can do here about it